# Apex Batch Test Class Does not seem to be executing the Execute Statement

Tags: apex, unit-test, batch

Based on the posts I read it seems like the consensus is the test record is not being created but I believe it has enough to create.  The execute part of the class never seems to fire.

The actual class does work as intended.

```
public class batch_delete_mdm_logger implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful
        {
            public integer recordsProcessed = 0;
            static string Query;
            date d = system.today().adddays(-1);     

            public Database.QueryLocator start (Database.BatchableContext bc)
            {

                //get qualifed records
                query =  'SELECT ';
                query += 'id ';        

                query += 'FROM ';
                query += 'mdm_logger__c ';

                query += 'WHERE ';
                query += 'CreatedDate ';
                query += '<= :d';

                return Database.getQueryLocator(Query);
            }

            public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<mdm_logger__c> scope)
            {
                delete scope;
            }

            public void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc)
            {
                //do code
            }

        }
```

Test class:

```
        @isTest
        private class batch_delete_mdm_logger_test
        {
            static void setup()
            {
                mdm_logger__c mdmLog_test = new mdm_logger__c
                (
                    Class_Method__c = 'future_callout',
                    Class_name__c = 'ws_mdm_contact',
                    Endpoint_Method__c = 'PUT',
                    Level__C = 'ERROR',
                    Message__c = 'FAKE',
                    Name = 'SomeName'
                );

                insert mdmLog_test;
            }

            static testMethod void test()
            {
                setup();
                test.startTest();
                list<mdm_logger__c> listTest = [select Level__C from mdm_logger__C where Level__C = 'ERROR'];
                id batchId = Database.executeBatch(new batch_delete_mdm_logger());
                test.stopTest();
                System.assertEquals(1, [select count() from mdm_logger__C where Level__C = 'ERROR']);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The record simply doesn't meet the criteria. Use Test.setCreatedDate to get the query going:

```
insert mdmLog_test;
Test.setCreatedDate(mdmLog_test.Id, DateTime.now().addDays(-3));
```

Comment: I am getting the following error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void setCreatedDate(Datetime) from the type System.Test

Comment: @Daryn Oops, forgot a parameter. Try it now.

Comment: That was it!  You are a genius sir.